# How can I unbind an MVC project from team foundation server? 

Tags: tfs

I can't get access to TFS (it does not exist anymore), but I want to edit the project. I want to break off the relation between my project and TFS, but see messages, such as "the file HomeCatalog.cs cannot be saved because it is write-protected".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Windows Explorer or whatever tool you prefer to Remove the read-only attribute from all the files in all folders of your project.

Comment: This doesn't help if you copied a folder from a previous source controlled folder to a new one.  To remove THOSE linkages, you need to follow Jehan33's solution below

Answer (score 3):

To unbind the project from team foundation server, open the project in solution explorer and go to File Menu, expand source control option and click on Change Source Control. Then, you will get a prompt to disassociate the solution from source control and you need to click yes.

Comment: Thanks, this allowed unbinding of the files in a very easy manner!